# return non-match value to as-is using qdaptools(lookup)

Tags: r, lookup

I have two dataframes:

```
state = c("CA","WA","OR","AZ")
first = c("Jim","Mick","Paul","Ron")
df1 <- data.frame(first, state)
df1
  first state
1   Jim    CA
2  Mick    WA
3  Paul    OR
4   Ron    AZ

newstate = c("TX", "LA")
first =c("Jim","Mick")
df2 <- data.frame(first,newstate)
df2
  first newstate
1   Jim       TX
2  Mick       LA
```

And i am using `qdaptools` lookup function:

```
library(qdaptools)
df1$match <- lookup(df1$first, df2[, 1:2])
> df1
  first state match
1   Jim    CA    TX
2  Mick    WA    LA
3  Paul    OR  <NA>
4   Ron    AZ  <NA>
```

Is there a way to ignore nomatch or have nomatch return the existing variable as-is? This would be example of desired result:

```
  first state match
1   Jim    CA    TX
2  Mick    WA    LA
3  Paul    OR    OR
4   Ron    AZ    AZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the dplyr package, you could do the job with `coalesce()`. Here, I converted factors to characters. If necessary, you want to reconvert them to factors. The first step is to merge the two data sets and convert factor to character. Then, you fill in NAs in `newstate` by using `coalesce()`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "first") %>%
mutate_all(funs(as.character)) %>%
mutate(newstate = coalesce(newstate, state))

#  first state newstate
#1   Jim    CA       TX
#2  Mick    WA       LA
#3  Paul    OR       OR
#4   Ron    AZ       AZ
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive way is to replace NA's with state value!

```
> state = c("CA","WA","OR","AZ")
> first = c("Jim","Mick","Paul","Ron")
> df1 <- data.frame(first, state, stringsAsFactors = F)
> df1
  first state
1   Jim    CA
2  Mick    WA
3  Paul    OR
4   Ron    AZ
> 
> newstate = c("TX", "LA")
> first =c("Jim","Mick")
> df2 <- data.frame(first,newstate, stringsAsFactors = F)
> df2
  first newstate
1   Jim       TX
2  Mick       LA
> 
> df3 <- merge(df1,df2, by='first', all=TRUE)
> 
> #df3 <- as.character(df3)
> 
> df3$newstate[is.na(df3$newstate)] <- df3$state[is.na(df3$newstate)]
> 
> df3
  first state newstate
1   Jim    CA       TX
2  Mick    WA       LA
3  Paul    OR       OR
4   Ron    AZ       AZ
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dplyer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, all.x = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(state = as.character(state),
         newstate = as.character(newstate),
         newstate = if_else(is.na(newstate), state, newstate))
```